# Prove or disprove an inequality problem

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $n\geq 1$ be an integer and let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be positive real numbers, all between $0$ and $1$.

Is it possible to prove or disprove:
$$
{(\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1-a_i))}{(1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i)}<1
$$
To prove this, I was able to prove this to be true if all  $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are the same which is$(1-a)^n(1+an)<1
$ using Bernoulli's Inequality:

Take $x$  root of the inequality:
$$(1-a)(1+an)^{1/a}\leqslant (1-n)(1+n)=1-n^2<1$$
But what if $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ do not have uniform values?

Comment: Wouldn't the case where all $a_i$ are equal translate to proving $(1-(1-a)^n)(1+na)<1$?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the original question @ShubhamJohri

Answer (score 2):

By AM-GM
$$\prod_{i=1}^n(1-a_i)\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)<\left(\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(1-a_i)+1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}=\left(\frac{n+1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}=1.$$
The equality does not occur because $1-a_i<1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i.$

Comment: Sorry, I edited the original question

Comment: @cscisgqr I also fixed. See now.

Comment: How did numerator become n+1? @Michael Rozenberg

Comment: @cscisgqr It's $1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n1=1+n$ and $-\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i+\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i=0.$

Comment: Nice application of AM-GM +1

Answer (score 1):

Note that $1+\sum_1^na_i<\prod_1^n(1+a_i)$

$\implies (\prod_1^n(1-a_i))(1+\sum_1^na_i)<(\prod_1^n(1-a_i))(\prod_1^n(1+a_i))=\prod_1^n(1-a_i^2)<1$

Comment: Beautiful solution! +1.